# View data from an Access table in another table

Tags: ms-access, join, foreign-keys, infopath

I am importing a bunch of data from an InfoPath file into an Access Database. I have several tables, each containing certain kinds of data. I would like each entry in the table to have the date, group number, and the shift along with the data so that the user can easily see which groups the data is coming from. The date, group, and shift data already exist in a separate table. I am thinking I need to create foreign keys or joins between tables but all of my attempts at that have filed to display what I want.

Any hints?

Comment: What setups have you tried? What happened? Why didn't it work like you wanted?

Comment: All I have really tried so far is using the Relationships tool with the goal of linking the primary key of the table with date, group, shift to a column I called Record ID in another table. The idea was to have a reference in each table that will allow the user to know which record input it is coming from since it is possible for one imported record to add only one row to a table but then multiple rows to another. It is not working the way I want because nothing is showing up in the Record ID column like I would like.

Comment: I think this is harder than usual because nothing is supposed to be manually entered into the database, eventually (if even possible) I would like to add a button in InfoPath that would do this automatically. Or maybe import the data through an email.

Comment: How is the infopath form generated/distributed now? was it created with the Email tool in Access? Does it get it's domain values from Access? is there a more natural key you can join on that an autonumber column? (that'd be ideal)

Comment: The InfoPath file is a form people fill out and send out to the whole company via email. Right now I am taking the data straight out of a saved InfoPath file I have saved to my computer. No data is coming from Access. And ideally, I would like to have Date, Group, and Shift on each table but they might not work as a primary key if someone submits more than on report on the same day for the same group and shift. Sorry this is so complicated. They know the emailing system is wack so they are having me try and see if there are any alternative storing solutions and they suggested I try Access.

Comment: This can be done with Managed email replies in Access (although the ability to create new email forms is [removed from 2013](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-access-2013-HA102749226.aspx)). You could alternatively hook your InfoPath form directly into Access and not embed any into in the form at all. As this question stands though it's pretty broad and probably unanswerable for this site.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for giving me another path to take!